# How do I avoid images being displaced?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 images with the css style `float:left`.

So they are placed next to each other; it's basically an image slider. The left image is a left arrow, the center images is the picture and the right image is a right arrow.

In the beginning, I hide the left arrow with jQuery, and when you push the right arrow I want the left arrow to unhide.  The problem is that when I do that, the picture gets pushed to the right a bit because the width of the left arrow affects the picture.

So how can I hide an images without it losing its width so the picture doesn't get shifted?

Comment: If you don't receive an answer you might also want to try http://doctype.com/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all you need to do is set the `visibility` style.  Something like:

```
$("#LeftArrowImage").css ('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Unlike jQuery's `hide()` or `display:none;`, `visibility:hidden;` preserves the layout effects of a node, without showing it.